# How to add Google sign-in using Firebase console

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have FCM implemented in my project, and I can see analytics and crash reports, now I need to add google sign in to the existing app. When I google it the google docs suggest to add app name, but when I click on the app name to download configuration file I'm unable to load the package name and site suggest to use firebase console to configure google services. Can any one help me out here?

Comment: Hi Praneeth. It's hard to picture what were the steps you already took. Could you post some screenshots (removing any sensitive details)?

Comment: in project setting you can add package name

Comment: @AL. sure I will post the screenshots

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?